# Type alias arguments in cppyy

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, cppyy

I'm trying to use some C++ libraries in Python code. One issue I've had is I can't seem to call functions that take an aliased type as an argument. Here is a minimal example I've reproduced:

```py
import cppyy

cppyy.cppdef(
    """
using namespace std;

enum class TestEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar
};

using TestDictClass = initializer_list<pair< TestEnum, int>>;

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(TestDictClass x);
};
"""
)

from cppyy.gbl.std import pair
from cppyy.gbl import TestEnum, TestDictClass, TestClass

TestPair = pair[TestEnum, int]
arg = TestDictClass([TestPair(TestEnum.Bar, 4), TestPair(TestEnum.Foo, 12)])
print("Arg is:")
print(arg)
print("\n")
print("Res is:")
res = TestClass(arg)
print(res)
```

This gives the output:

```
Arg is:
<cppyy.gbl.std.initializer_list<std::pair<TestEnum,int> > object at 0x09646008>


Res is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\scratch\test-alias.py", line 31, in <module>
    res = TestClass(arg)
TypeError: none of the 3 overloaded methods succeeded. Full details:
  TestClass::TestClass(TestDictClass x) =>
    TypeError: could not convert argument 1
  TestClass::TestClass(TestClass&&) =>
    ValueError: could not convert argument 1 (object is not an rvalue)
  TestClass::TestClass(const TestClass&) =>
    TypeError: could not convert argument 1
```

Please note my C++ experience is quite limited. Is the issue the type alias, or something else? If it's the type conversion, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the alias, just that the converter code is not expecting an explicit `std::initializer_list` object, only the implicit conversions. This will work:

```
res = TestClass([TestPair(TestEnum.Bar, 4), TestPair(TestEnum.Foo, 12)])
```

Edit: cppyy with repo master, the above now works as well.